# Encoding of a post request

Tags: .net, http, post, character-encoding

In my web.config file I have following line:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
```

So I understand that server will interpret browser post request as utf-8. 
I used firebug and I check the encoding of post request is:

```
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
```

Everything works fine, but I have following questions:

1. What will happen if post will be in a different encoding?
2. Is there a way to set encoding of a post request in a browser options (so I could test
   that)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - `Accept-Encoding` relates to transfer-encoding of a response (a value of `gzip, deflate` means that the client will happily accept a compressed response that was compressed with either `gzip` or `deflate` compression).

It is *not* the *character-encoding* of the actual text, which is typically included as part of the `Content-Type` header in requests and responses - e.g. `text/html; charset=UTF-8` (the last bit after the semi colon there being the character encoding).

So a client can explicitly provide the character encoding of a request body by providing an additional `"; charset=[name]"` suffix to the content-type header - although a browser will automatically select the correct one based on the user's locale (e.g. if Japanese it might use utf-16 I guess).  Although it doesn't mean anything if the underlying bytes are not also written to that encoding.

Often browsers will not include a specific character encoding; and equally neither will servers (although more often than not they do now).

The globalization element then is used to determine what encoding the server will ***assume*** if *no character encoding is specified in a request, or if equally it's not explicitly set by a page in a response*.  This is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx).

It does not, therefore, affect your application's ability to interpret other character encodings - as long as the client forms the request correctly, the server will be able to decode the request.

Comment: Thank you for clarification :)

My task is to check if is possible to submit text by a form and submitted text will be bad interpreted by a server. And after your answer I think it is very hard.
 I added to form tag following attributes

    enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-2" accept-charset="ISO-8859-2"
And after submission of Cyrillic text server still interprets its well.